# Integer arithmetic: Add 1 to UINT_MAX and divide by n without overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow, integer-division

Is there a way to compute the result of `((UINT_MAX+1)/x)*x-1` 
in C without resorting to `unsigned long` (where `x` is `unsigned int`)?
(respective "without resorting to `unsigned long long`" depending on architecture.)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Is your x, by chance, a power of 2 ?

Comment: This is the maximum multiple of x within the range of a `unsigned int` decremented by one.

Comment: Your expression simplifies to UINT_MAX, unless you forgot to add some parenthesis.

Comment: In C: "When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded."

Comment: related: [How to compute 2⁶⁴/n in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55565537/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather simple arithmetic:

```
((UINT_MAX + 1) / x) * x - 1 =
((UINT_MAX - x + x + 1) / x) * x - 1 = 
((UINT_MAX - x + 1) / x + 1) * x - 1 =
(UINT_MAX - x + 1) / x) * x + (x - 1)
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the one I gave.

Comment: x can't be > UINT_MAX.

Comment: @chmike Thanks for pointing that out. I did not read the question carefully and thought that x is of type unsigned long rather than unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

With integer divisions we have the following equivalence

```
(y/x)*x == y - y%x
```

So we have

```
((UINT_MAX+1)/x)*x-1 == UINT_MAX - (UINT_MAX+1)%x
```

combining this result with the following equivalence

```
(UINT_MAX+1)%x == ((UINT_MAX % x) +1)%x
```

we get

```
((UINT_MAX+1)/x)*x-1 == UINT_MAX - ((UINT_MAX % x) +1)%x
```

which is computable with an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score -2):

sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(unsigned int) == 4 on most modern compilers.  You might want to use use unsigned long long.

Comment: It is a requirement of the question to not use `unsigned long long`.