# How to compute 2⁶⁴/n in C?

Tags: c, integer-division

How to compute the integer division, 2<sup>64</sup>/n? Assuming:

- `unsigned long` is 64-bit
- We use a 64-bit CPU
- 1 < n < 2<sup>64</sup>

If we do `18446744073709551616ul / n`, we get `warning: integer constant is too large for its type` at compile time. This is because we cannot express 2<sup>64</sup> in a 64-bit CPU. Another way is the following:

```
#define IS_POWER_OF_TWO(x) ((x & (x - 1)) == 0)

unsigned long q = 18446744073709551615ul / n;
if (IS_POWER_OF_TWO(n))
    return q + 1;
else
    return q;
```

Is there any faster (CPU cycle) or cleaner (coding) implementation?

Comment: 128 bit would certainly work. Alternatively, you can try using double division...

Comment: if your compiler has `__int128` then the clean way is `__int128 q = ((__int128)18446744073709551615ull + 1)/n`

Comment: @mvp AFAIK, `double` is 64-bit, so we need 128-bit quadruple.

Comment: IEEE754 double has 53 bits

Comment: @phuclv I tried to disassemble your code. It turns out to be calling `__divti3`, which is a bit overkill for the job.

Comment: yes, I mean clean in terms of code. I didn't say that it's efficient in terms of CPU cycle

Comment: Seems like it would be nicer to write `18446744073709551615ul` as `-1ul`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't know we have negative unsigned constants. Yes. That's definitely more readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll use `uint64_t` here (which needs the `<stdint.h>` include) so as not to require your assumption about the size of `unsigned long`.

phuclv's idea of using `-n` is clever, but can be made much simpler.  As unsigned 64-bit integers, we have -n = 2<sup>64</sup>-n, then (-n)/n = 2<sup>64</sup>/n - 1, and we can simply add back the 1.

```
uint64_t divide_two_to_the_64(uint64_t n) {
  return (-n)/n + 1;
}
```

The generated code is just what you would expect (gcc 8.3 on x86-64 via [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/M9keg9)):

```
    mov     rax, rdi
    xor     edx, edx
    neg     rax
    div     rdi
    add     rax, 1
    ret
```

Comment: Quite an astute observation. It seems to hold with an `if (twoPow64divphuclv (v) != twoPow64divnate (v)) { /* throw error */ }` for as many numbers as I was willing to wait through `:)` Though I did make yours `uint64_t twoPow64divnate (uint64_t n)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if you can do 1 billion iterations a second, it'll take you ~585 years to loop through all possible `int64_t` values, so unfortunately you have to test a 32-bit version and then check if it work for some 64-bit values

Comment: nice but wouldn't it be better to use standard `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long` ? unsigned long isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits, even on a 64 bits compiler

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Sure, if you like.  The question explicitly stated their assumption that `unsigned long` is 64 bits on the system of interest, so I was just staying consistent with that.  But I've changed it now.

Answer (score 7):

I've come up with another solution which was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950055/995714). From there we know that

> (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>)/n =
>
> (a<sub>1</sub>/n + a<sub>2</sub>/n + a<sub>3</sub>/n + ... + a<sub>n</sub>/n) + (a<sub>1</sub> % n + a<sub>2</sub> % n + a<sub>3</sub> % n + ... + a<sub>n</sub> % n)/n

By choosing ***a<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>3</sub> = ... = a<sub>n-1</sub> = 1*** and ***a<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>64</sup> - n*** we'll have

> (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>)/n = (1 + 1 + 1 + ... + (2<sup>64</sup> - n))/n = 2<sup>64</sup>/n
>
> = [(n - 1)*1/n + (2<sup>64</sup> - n)/n] + [(n - 1)*0 + (2<sup>64</sup> - n) % n]/n
>
> = (2<sup>64</sup> - n)/n + ((2<sup>64</sup> - n) % n)/n

***2<sup>64</sup> - n*** is the 2's complement of n, which is `-n`, or we can also write it as `~0 - n + 1`. So the final solution would be

```
uint64_t twoPow64div(uint64_t n)
{
    return (-n)/n + (n + (-n) % n)/n + (n > 1ULL << 63);
}
```

The last part is to correct the result, because we deal with unsigned integers instead of signed ones like in the other question. Checked both 32 and 64-bit versions on my PC and the result matches with your solution

On MSVC however there's an [intrinsic for 128-bit division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/udiv128?view=vs-2019), so you can use like this

```
uint64_t remainder;
return _udiv128(1, 0, n, &remainder);
```

which results in the cleanest output

```
    mov     edx, 1
    xor     eax, eax
    div     rcx
    ret     0
```

Here's the [demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cintrin.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(-n)/n+%2B+(n+%2B+(-n)+%25+n)/n+%2B+(n+%3E+1ULL+%3C%3C+63)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div2(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(-n)/n+%2B+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div3(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++uint64_t+remainder%3B%0A++++return+_udiv128(1,+0,+n,+%26remainder)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:26.649248856956245,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_20_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:/Ox,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.20+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:73.3507511430438,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

On most x86 compilers (one notable exception is MSVC) [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) also has 64 bits of precision, so you can use either of these

```
(uint64_t)(powl(2, 64)/n)
(uint64_t)(((long double)~0ULL)/n)
(uint64_t)(18446744073709551616.0L/n)
```

although probably the performance would be worse. This can also be applied to any implementations where `long double` has more than 63 bits of significand, like [PowerPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60785089/995714) with its [double-double implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic)

There's a related question about calculating `((UINT_MAX + 1)/x)*x - 1`:  [Integer arithmetic: Add 1 to UINT_MAX and divide by n without overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29182036/995714) with also clever solutions. Based on that we have

> 2<sup>64</sup>/n = (2<sup>64</sup> - n + n)/n = (2<sup>64</sup> - n)/n + 1 = (-n)/n + 1

which is essentially just another way to get [Nate Eldredge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584872/995714)

Here's some demo for other compilers on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(-n)/n+%2B+(n+%2B+(-n)+%25+n)/n+%2B+(n+%3E+1ULL+%3C%3C+63)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div2(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(-n)/n+%2B+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+twoPow64div3(uint64_t+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(uint64_t)(18446744073709551616.0L/n)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:26.649248856956245,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dnative%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppc64leg630,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mregnames%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27power64le+gcc+6.3.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips564,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27MIPS64+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:73.3507511430438,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

See also:

- [Trick to divide a constant (power of two) by an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35063224/995714)
- [Efficient computation of 2**64 / divisor via fast floating-point reciprocal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36853827/995714)

Comment: Since `(-n) /n` equals (2^64-n)/n = 2^64/n - 1, can't we just say `(-n)/n + 1`?  It seems to give the right answer in all of my tests.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @NateEldredge good point. I didn't think of that but it seems reasonable

Answer (score 2):

> We use a 64-bit CPU

Which 64-bit CPU?

In general, if you multiply a number with N bits by another number that has M bits, the result will have up to N+M bits. For integer division it's similar - if a number with N bits is divided by a number with M bits the result will have N-M+1 bits.

Because multiplication is naturally "widening" (the result has more digits than either of the source numbers) and integer division is naturally "narrowing" (the result has less digits); some CPUs support "widening multiplication" and "narrowing division".

In other words, some 64-bit CPUs support dividing a 128-bit number by a 64-bit number to get a 64-bit result. For example, on 80x86 it's a single `DIV` instruction.

Unfortunately, C doesn't support "widening multiplication" or "narrowing division". It only supports "result is same size as source operands".

Ironically (for unsigned 64-bit divisors on 64-bit 80x86) there is no other choice and the compiler must use the `DIV` instruction that will divide a 128-bit number by a 64-bit number. This means that the C language forces you to use a 64-bit numerator, then the code generated by the compiler extends your 64 bit numerator to 128 bits and divides it by a 64 bit number to get a 64 bit result; and then you write extra code to work around the fact that the language prevented you from using a 128-bit numerator to begin with.

Hopefully you can see how this situation might be considered "less than ideal".

What I'd want is a way to trick the compiler into supporting "narrowing division". For example, maybe by abusing casts and hoping that the optimiser is smart enough, like this:

```
  __uint128_t numerator = (__uint128_t)1 << 64;
  if(n > 1) {
      return (uint64_t)(numerator/n);
  }
```

I tested this for the latest versions of GCC, CLANG and ICC (using https://godbolt.org/ ) and found that (for 64-bit 80x86) none of the compilers are smart enough to realise that a single `DIV` instruction is all that is needed (they all generated code that does a `call __udivti3`, which is an expensive function to get a 128 bit result). The compilers will only use `DIV` when the (128-bit) numerator is 64 bits (and it will be preceded by an `XOR RDX,RDX` to set the highest half of the 128-bit numerator to zeros).

In other words, it's likely that the only way to get ideal code (the `DIV` instruction by itself on 64-bit 80x86) is to resort to inline assembly.

For example, the best code you'll get without inline assembly (from Nate Eldredge's answer) will be:

```
    mov     rax, rdi
    xor     edx, edx
    neg     rax
    div     rdi
    add     rax, 1
    ret
```

...and the best code that's possible is:

```
    mov     edx, 1
    xor     rax, rax
    div     rdi
    ret
```

Comment: A minor disadvantage (or maybe advantage?) of the "best possible" code is that if you should accidentally try it with `n=1`, you will get a divide error exception.  The other suggestions all return 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes - that's why I needed to put the `if(n > 1)` when testing in godbolt (to make sure it's possible for compiler to know `n` can't be 1).

Comment: Current compilers are also not smart enough to convert a division of a `__(u)int128_t` by a constant into a multiplication and calls the division function instead. And  instead of `xor rax, rax` you should use `xor eax, eax`

Answer (score 1):

Your way is pretty good.  It *might* be better to write it like this:

```
return 18446744073709551615ul / n + ((n&(n-1)) ? 0:1);
```

The hope is to make sure the compiler notices that it can do a conditional move instead of a branch.

Compile and disassemble.

Comment: Interestingly, gcc 7 and 8 both compile your code with a conditional set, whose result is added.  For the original code, gcc 7 does a conditional move.  gcc 8 does a very clever `cmp rdi, 1 ; adc rax, 0` (!).

Comment: Wow, that is very clever.  I would be happy with any of these results, but your `-n/n+1` is much better, of course -- I'm disappointed that I didn't think of it.